# Inexplicable error when trying to export my R notebook

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Getting this error from R Markdown when trying to export my .RMD

```
"Error in filter(Gastropods, Species == "Cellana") :  object 'Species' not found Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> filter"
```

However, all my plots are coming out successfully. I can clearly see in the data that the species column is there and that Cellana is a species. No spelling errors or anything.

My first 20 or so lines of code are below

````
###
---
title: " Lab Report 2 - z5016113"
output: html_notebook
i---

#1. Gastropod abundance vs. height on the shore

```{r}
Gastropods <- read.csv(file = "MaroubraZones.csv", header = TRUE)
library(ggplot2, dplyr)
```

```{r}
Gastropods$Zone <- factor(Gastropods$Zone, levels = c("Low", "Mid", "High"))
```

```{r}
Cellana <- filter(Gastropods, Species == "Cellana")  ------> This line is causing the error
```

```{r}
ggplot(Cellana, aes(Zone, Abundance)) + geom_boxplot()
```
###
````

Comment: Check `colnames(Gastropods)`, maybe add it to your question as well.

Comment: Wait, you don't load `dplyr` or `tidyverse` within your R code. RMarkdown always starts a fresh session when knitting, so you need to make sure to load any relevant libraries in a code chunk.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might be a bigger issue with DPLYR and filter and I found other posts suggesting they had the same problem and the answer seemed to add `dplyr::filter` rather than just `filter` in the command.  [Link to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406890/filter-in-dplyr-returning-error)

It might also be worth testing this by filtering out the mollusc of interest before you convert it to a factor?

I have also had similar issues filtering items out and a restart of R fixed the issue.

Comment: You can sometimes get issues like this depending on the order you  load different libraries, but your answer made me notice that OP hadn't actually loaded `dplyr` in his code, which is more likely as the source of the error than the library order issue.

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr::filter` has not been found because you haven't loaded `dplyr`, but since there are other function named `filter` in other packages, it tries to apply those instead (and fails).

From `?library`:

> library(package, [...])
>
> [...]
>
> **package**    the name of a package, given as a name or literal
>   character string, or a character string, depending on whether
>   character.only is FALSE (default) or TRUE).

This means you can only load *one* package at a time. Here, you are trying to load both `ggplot2` and `dplyr` in the same call. Only `ggplot2` is loaded. The correct way to do this is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```